# react/react-router-dom 6.0.0/Navlink isActive не работает для ссылок с русским языком

Tags: react-router-dom

`<NavLink to="/link" className={({isActive})=> isActive ? "class1" : "class2"}>page</NavLink>` -работает
`<NavLink to="/ссылка" className={({isActive})=> isActive ? "class1" : "class2"}>page</NavLink>` -не работает(isActive не срабатывает если в пути есть что-то кроме английских букв)

Можно ли это исправить без костылей?

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было обернуть `to={encodeURI("/ссылка")}` и все заработает. При этом внешне ссылка отображается как обычно. И при использовании хука useParams ничего менять не нужно